# Checar si al archivo (file) es imagen o video en php? usando framework laravel

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema, no logro solucionar este problema acerca de mostrar contenido en mi vista. 
Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos que se llama galerias:

- idGaleria
- url
- idUsuario

Lo que registro en esa tabla, es la url donde almaceno el archivo ya sea fotos o vídeos. Esta parte de subir imágenes y vídeos ya me funciona, el problema es que ahora quiero visualizar en una vista todo ese contenido, pero el único problema es cuando recorro la tabla, visualizo todo en una etiqueta img, pero si es un video obviamente no lo va reconocer, entonces la única solución que encontré fue desde el controlador verificar si es una imagen que guarde todo en una variable $imagenes  y  si es video en  $videos, esto se deberá visualizar mi vista blade, pero el único problema que tengo es como debo verificar si es un video o imagen. No sé si me logran comprender 
En mi vista tengo este codigo para visualizar el contenido de la consulta desde el controlador haciendo uso del metodo index;

```
<div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Mi galeria</h5>
               <hr>
              <div class="row" >
                 @foreach ($galerias as $galeria)
                     <div class="col-12 col-md-2" style="height:100px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                            <div  class="card" style=" height:100%;">

                              @if($galeria->url)
                                      <img src="{{ url($galeria->url) }}" class="card-img-top" style="height:100%;">
                              @endif
                            </div>
                     </div>
                 @endforeach
              </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Y como resultado de la vista, obtengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El único problema es cuando recorro la variable todo lo visualizo en la etiqueta img, por eso decía que en el controlador realizar dos variables para separar los imagenes y videos de las rutas.

Código de mi controlador index, lo cual no tiene mucha importancia

```
public function index()
    {
        $galerias= Galeria::get();
        return view('vistaGaleria',compact('galerias'));
    }
```

En la base de datos lo unico que almaceno es la url que seria algo asi:

```
/imagenes/5c2db5a7705b520631811_1425711934186283_992917833_n.jpg
```

Comment: Creo que tienes la respuesta en la extensión de la URL, si es imagen ira con jpg y si es video con otra, ya con eso puedes diferenciarlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con la extension al final de la url del archivo puedes diferenciar entre video o imagen:

```
 @foreach ($galerias as $galeria)
                 <div class="col-12 col-md-2" style="height:100px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                        <div  class="card" style=" height:100%;">

                          @if($galeria->url)
                              @php
                                 $extension = pathinfo($galeria->url)['extension'];
                              @endphp
                              @if($extension=="jpg" || $extension == "jpeg")
                                  <img src="{{ url($galeria->url) }}" class="card-img-top" style="height:100%;">
                              @else
                                 // aqui tu video en la etiqueta que corresponda {{ url($galeria->url) }}
                              @endif
                          @endif
                        </div>
                 </div>
             @endforeach
```

Comment: Me funciono muy bien!!!!